# $_POST as a variable

Tags: php

Hello guys i have seen a code which uses $_POST as a variable .The code is

```
private
$something

function example()
if($_POST) $_POST = $this->$something-1;
if($_SESSION) $_SESSION = $this+1;
if($_COOKIES) $_ COOKIES = $this->something
```

In this code i have seen $_POST as a variable .Can we us $_POST as a variable instead of

```
$code = $_POST['code']
```

I am sorry if i asked this question wrongly .Please help me ..:) .Thanks in advance

Comment: `$something = $_POST;` will make you able to use `$something['code']` later, which I find completely useless

Comment: You should try to follow well-known practices otherwise other developers will have a hard time following your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked a few times and the general consensus seems to be that there is no issue referencing the `$_POST` variable directly. In fact by using the line

```
$code = $_POST['code']
```

You are in fact adding more code and more work for yourself.

But it is entirely up to you as to how you use `$_POST`, either way is fine.

**Update**

You do not necessarily need data posted to the page in order to use $_POST see below

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); //return blank array as nothing has been posted to the page
echo '</pre>'; 

$_POST[] = 1; //even though no data has been posted we can use $_POST as a variable if we wish

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // This will print an array where $_POST[0] is equal to 1
echo '</pre>';

$_POST[0] = $_POST[0] + 1;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // This will print an array where $_POST[0] is equal to 2 as we added one earlier
echo '</pre>';
```

So here we can see the use of `$_POST`. In the third print we have altered the `$_POST[0]` value. You can also as shown in your code, make `$_POST` represent a single value rather than an array which is default.

Therefore if we do say

```
$_POST = 1+1;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // This will print 2
echo '</pre>';
```

This will print 2.

Much like any variable you can use $_POST as a variable name, though I would not recommend this unless dealing with posted data.

Comment: didnt got ur answer ?

Comment: my question is that can we use $_post as a varibale like $_POST = $somthing +$code ..Can we use like that ?

Answer (score 1):

A legitimate use of $_POST without a *key* as in

```
$_POST['email']
```

would be ...

```
is_array($_POST)
```

This is not using $_POST as a variable, but it is an example of using the $_POST identifier without trying to access one of its elements. Based on your example, this *might* be something everyone should do before using $_POST?